# Cannot find drive in PowerShell Scripting

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
does not exist.
At E:\Uniformance Insight R102 Diagnostic Capture Tool (1).ps1:12 char:17
+ $InstallInfo = (Get-ItemProperty %SystemDrive%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:SOFTWARE\Wow64 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (%SystemDrive%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:String) [Get-ItemProperty], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

This is the issue I'm facing. How do I resolve this?

Comment: PowerShell doesn't support %-variables, and `%systemdrive%` would be invalid for a registry path anyway.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code instead. I can only give what is shown in your post, so the code is obviously not complete, you'll need to add in the rest of the line.

```
$InstallInfo = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow64....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check your privacy and folder permissions.

Specially - Firewall , I have seen such issues and was able to fix when I turned off the firewall settings.

But make sure you are aware about this sensitive settings before you proceed.